# Mysql query creation for table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table name : data
```

My database table is:

```
id      range   number     value   

1          a      no1        100
2          b      no1        101
3          a      no2        102
4          c      no2        103
5          a      no3        104
6          b      no3        105
```

I need output like

```
range   no1   no2  no3   

a       100   102   104
b       101    0    105
c       0     103   0
```

Please anyone help for me for writing mysql query:((((

Comment: What do u want? sum of value or  max of value?

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: i don't need sum, i need arrangement of range wise data... example a has 10 number(no10) and b has 9numbers(no9) i need to arrange this number in row wise only

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select range,
       max(case when number = 'no1' then value else 0 end) as no1,
       max(case when number = 'no2' then value else 0 end) as no2,
       max(case when number = 'no3' then value else 0 end) as no3
from t
group by range;
```